# How can a Ultralow Voltage Step-Up converters start up?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I've read about step up converters working from unbelievably low voltages (20mV), namely the LTC3108. How can circuits even start at those low voltages? 
Diodes, FETs and BJTs shouldn't switch at 20mV.

What is the concept behind it?

[Link to the actual IC](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3108)

Comment: There is a 1:100 transformer on the input

Comment: Does V_aux play a role in this?

Comment: @Mike  The transformer doesn't step-up until it sees AC component on the primary side.  But the input can be something like a thermoelectric generator that creates only DC.  Of course, the DC can be chopped, and that's what SW (switch) is doing.  But how would the chopper start/prime the switch if 20mV is all that there is?  That's the conundrum behind this question.

Comment: @Nick, I took a shot at explaining it, can you see if it makes any sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I studied the patent that was briefly briefly shown to us by user @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams to the extent that I begin to understand the operation of it. The patent doesn't exactly describe the operation of LTC3108 but something very similar to it. Here's what I made of it. Feel free to offer any corrections.

Consider the following picture, taken from the [patent](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US4734658):

[image: http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US4734658]

At the heart of it, there is Q1, a junction FET whose threshold voltage is very near zero volts. So near, in fact, that ambient noise of the current source (thermopile or whatever) causes changes in the conductivity of Q1. This causes changes in the current through the primary winding of the transformer T1, which transforms the changes in current to changes in voltage at the secondary winding, at the ratio of the windings of the transformer, for example 1:100. These are then fed back to the gate of the FET, in the case of this schematic at an inverted phase, so that Q1 will further amplify the noise oscillations. The net effect is that whenever sufficient current is provided by the current source, the circuit formed by Q1, C1 and T1 quickly begins to oscillate at a roughly known rate.

As the oscillation starts, an AC voltage is formed at the secondary winding of T1. This will then be rectified, regulated and used to power up the circuitry.

Comment: Thank you. I think that's the principle, also on LTs site I found a FAQ about the chip: 
Q. Do we have any patents on the LTC3108 or LTC3109?
A. We don’t on the LTC3108. ...is covered by numerous patents dating back over 20 years, and is now public domain...

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for the info from the LT's FAQ. It's very interesting. I'm beginning to see some applications for this fancy little item. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Cheers!

Comment: that's it.  Also, in it is possible to have "native" transistors in some processes with very low threshold voltages.  That would modulate the transformer primary.

Answer (score 1):

From the data-sheet , page 9.

> The active circuits within the LTC3108 are powered from VAUX, which should be bypassed with a 1μF capacitor.

So it can't start up on it's own.

and from page 10.

> In a typical application, a storage capacitor (typically a few hundred microfarads) is connected to VOUT. As soon as VAUX exceeds 2.5V, the VOUT capacitor will be allowed to charge up to its regulated voltage. The current available to charge the capacitor will depend on the input voltage and transformer turns ratio, but is limited to about 4.5mA typical.

and also from page 10:

> VSTORE
>   The VSTORE output can be used to charge a large storage capacitor or rechargeable battery after VOUT has reached regulation. Once VOUT has reached regulation, the VSTORE output will be allowed to charge up to the VAUX voltage. The storage element on VSTORE can be used to power the system in the event that the input source is lost, or is unable to provide the current demanded by the VOUT, VOUT2 and LDO outputs. If VAUX drops below VSTORE, the LTC3108 will automatically draw current from the storage element. Note that it may take a long time to charge a large capacitor, depending on the input energy available and the loading on VOUT and VLDO.

On edit, leaving this up because shows the historical aspect of how the solution was found. Correct answer lies elsewhere.

Comment: Are you quite sure on that? I became very interested myself on this and I've also been combing through the very interesting datasheet. The patent cited and then deleted by @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams (http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US4734658) a few minutes ago seemed quite interesting and relevant. I for one would like to have a definite answer on this. And using charge injection, you can pick any threshold voltage for a FET, even zero or a negative voltage, doesn't matter if it's NFET or PFET, so this just might be very interesting. The patent talks about amplifying ambient noise to start the osc

Comment: I think it means when the the voltage is stepped up to a reasonable level at VAUX, only then it will charge the output capacitors. On all the application notes VAUX is directly connected to a capacitor that is grounded.

Comment: Yep, see additional posted material

Comment: @placeholder, I'm still not convinced. None of those paragraphs talk anything about starting. But in the Electrical Characteristics at page 2 it says: "Minimum Start-Up Voltage Using 1:100 Transformer Turns Ratio, VAUX = 0V Typ. 20 mV Max. 50 mV.". What if VAUX is also an output of the DCDC converter?

Comment: @placeholder I have found a site which uses the chip in an application [Link](http://harizanov.com/wiki/wiki-home/ltc3108-energy-harvesting-breakout-board/). He doesn't use VAUX in that way.

Comment: Datasheet page 7: VAUX (Pin 1/Pin 2): Output of the Internal Rectifier Circuit and VCC for the IC.

Comment: @PkP It certainly is ambiguous isn't it? Figure 1 on page 11 shows VStore a zero initially and Vaux also very low. Hmmm

Comment: @placeholder, Yeah, this is/was definitely an interesting brainpuzzler. But I think I've cracked it. What do you think about my attempt at an explanation?

Comment: @PkP Found it! Page 6, start up voltage sequncing, shows at least 20 seconds before the rails come alive.